# How to write xpath for blow code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There are no of elements in a table this is 43 record and I want to click on this id and for this I am not able to identify the Xpath
please help me

My HTML code is as below :-

```
<a class="btn btn-gray btn-sm show-tooltip" href="/MCare_Test/Auhmc/Admin/Provider/AddDoctor/43" data-title="Add Doctor" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="tooltip629994">
```

Thanks in Advance
Srinu M

Comment: where is the HTML code?

Comment: <a class="btn btn-gray btn-sm show-tooltip" href="/MCare_Test/Auhmc/Admin/Provider/AddDoctor/43" data-title="Add Doctor" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="tooltip484761">

Comment: can you please share your all other rows also.. it will help us to help you

Comment: Are you looking only to use XPath. How about CssSelector?

Comment: please send me the Cssselector

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath

```
//a[@aria-describedby='tooltip629994']
```

OR

```
 //a[@class='btn btn-gray btn-sm show-tooltip']
```

OR

```
//a[@aria-describedby='tooltip629994' and @class='btn btn-gray btn-sm show-tooltip']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XPath:

`//a[@data-title='Add Doctor']`

Comment: Thanks to one and all

Comment: You're welcome. Upvote the answer that helped you resolve the issue and mark it as the answer to close the question.